# Integral $\int_0^{\infty} r^2 \exp (-\frac{r^2}{2}) dr$

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function, improper-integrals

Consider
$$\int_0^{\infty} r^2 \exp (-\frac{r^2}{2})\,dr.$$
I have tried several times by parts but still do not get it.
I know the solution is $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2}}$ but I do not know how to get it.

Any hint?

Comment: use substitution and convert it to Gamma function.

Comment: You probably want to pick $u=r$ and $dv = r e^{-r^2/2}\, dr$.

Comment: Just to extend @Nosrati's comment: write it on the format

$$
\Gamma(z) = \int_0^\infty x^{z-1} e^{-x}\,dx,
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrating by parts is a good idea. A primitive of $re^{-\frac{r^2}2}$ is $-e^{-\frac{r^2}2}$. So,\begin{align}\int_0^\infty r^2e^{-\frac{r^2}2}&=\left[-re^{-\frac{r^2}2}\right]_{r=0}^{r\to\infty}+\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{r^2}2}\,\mathrm dr\\&=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{\sqrt2}.\end{align}

Comment: How do you know that the integral of this exponential has that result?

Comment: Doing $r=\sqrt2 u$ and $\mathrm dr=\sqrt 2\mathrm du$, you get that$$\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{r^2}2}\,\mathrm dr=\sqrt2\int_0^\infty e^{-u^2}\,\mathrm du=\frac1{\sqrt2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u^2}\,\mathrm du.$$And it is a well-known result that$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u^2}\mathrm du=\sqrt\pi.$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=r$, $v'=r\exp(-\frac{r^2}{2})$. Then we know that, by integration by parts,

$$\int_0^{\infty} r^2 \exp (-\frac{r^2}{2})\,dr.=\int_0^\infty uv\,dr=[uv]_0^\infty-\int_0^\infty u'v\, dr$$

which is just

$$-\int_0^\infty v\, dr=\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}\, dr=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\int_0^\infty\exp(-\alpha r^2)dr=\frac12\pi^{1/2}\alpha^{-1/2}$, applying $-\partial_\alpha$ gives $\int_0^\infty r^2\exp(-\alpha r^2)dr=\frac14\pi^{1/2}\alpha^{-3/2}$. With $\alpha=\frac12$, your integral is $\frac14\pi^{1/2}2^{3/2}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$.

Answer (score 1):

The integral $I=\int_0^{\infty}  r^2\exp (-\frac{r^2}{2})\,dr$ can be evaluated as a double integral:
$$1\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}=\int_0^{\infty} x \exp (-\frac{x^2}{2})dx \cdot \int_0^{\infty} \exp (-\frac{y^2}{2})dy \\=\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos(\theta)d\theta\int_0^{\infty}  r^2\exp (-\frac{r^2}{2})dr=1\cdot I.$$
P.S. Recall that the non-trivial integral $J=\int_0^{\infty} \exp (-\frac{y^2}{2})dy$ can be evaluated in a similar way:
$$J^2=\int_0^{\infty} \exp (-\frac{x^2}{2})dx\cdot \int_0^{\infty} \exp (-\frac{y^2}{2})dy\\=
\int_0^{\pi/2}d\theta\int_0^{\infty} r\exp (-\frac{r^2}{2})dr=\pi/2\cdot 1.$$